# Transaction rollback not working using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, transactions

I am trying to rollback my query using transactions in codeigniter however it doesn't work. I am writing a script for inserting csv data into mysql by cron.Insert query is working but since it will run through cron if something goes wrong and the query stops in middle I want to rollback the transactions as it will create conflict in the data if I re-run the script again.
I tried searching for answers but couldn't find exact solution for this.I will appreciate if anyone could help me on this.
Below is my code -

```
function loadPstnM2OnoffData($filePath,$fileName){
    $this->db->trans_begin();
    //$this->db->trans_strict(FALSE);
    $this->db->query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '".$filePath."'
    INTO TABLE tbl_pstn_m2_on_off
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'
    (on_off_id,cli,cli_id,type,on_off,received_date,unit,description,type1,type2,@filename)
    SET filename='".$fileName."'");

    //$this->db->trans_complete();

    if ($this->db->trans_status() === FALSE)
    {
        $this->db->trans_rollback();
         //return FALSE;
        echo "fail";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->db->trans_commit();
         //return TRUE;
    }

}
```